# Generating Presign URL for set of image files

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

Is it possible to call AWS API only once, specifically `Presign` function, in order to obtain Authorization token, and then use it for set of, lets say 50, image files on S3?

I don't want to invoke AWS API **X** times in order to generate URLs for image files on S3. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a pre-sign SDK method, in any of the SDKs, that accepts a list of S3 keys.

However, you should just go ahead and call the pre-sign method, file by file. It's not a network API call. It's a purely local signing operation.